# Как использовать string?

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

Пытаюсь сделать простенький проект с использованием winforms на C++/CLI. Мне понадобилось создать класс (создал я его в .cpp файле). И в этом классе мне нужно сделать поле с типом данных string. Но при попытке создать его, появляется ошибка: "Идентификатор "string" не определен", хотя я использовал #include  в хедере формы. Также пробовал прописывать инклуд в самом .cpp файле, но все равно вылазит эта ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо

```
string name;
```

надо писать

```
std::string name;
```